# Hibernate - Retrieve all table info - column name, indexes, length and populate as table

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, metadata

Do we have any hibernate function which can be used to retrieve all the table info such as column name, indexes, length and populate as table in the front end.

If not possible in hibernate, do we need to write DB dependent SQL script for the same.

This will help to provide a page for diagnosis when required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JDBC DatabaseMetaData](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/databasemetadata.html).

But if you want a state-of-the-art database schema Java representation, then there's only one tool to satisfy your need, and its name is [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/).

You can even [generate jOOQ table mappings from JPA Annotations](http://vladmihalcea.com/jooq-facts-from-jpa-annotations-to-jooq-table-mappings/).

You can also use the [DSLContext.meta()](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.5.x/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#meta--) or even the [jooq-meta](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-meta) module, if you just want the code generation part of jOOQ.